# Android get location or prompt to enable location service if disabled

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I've found bits and pieces of this answer scattered through other posts, but I wanted to record it here for others.

How can I simply request the user's GPS and/or Network location and, if they haven't enabled the service, prompt them to do so?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to capture the location on a button push, here's how you'd do it.  If the user does not have a location service enabled, this will send them to the settings menu to enable it.

First, you must add the permission "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" to your manifest.  If you need GPS (network location isn't sensitive enough), add the permission "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" instead, and change the "Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE" to "Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE"

```
Button gpsButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonGPSLocation);
gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Start loction service
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)[OUTERCLASS].this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
        locationCritera.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        locationCritera.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        locationCritera.setBearingRequired(false);
        locationCritera.setCostAllowed(true);
        locationCritera.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

        String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera, true);

        if (providerName != null && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(providerName)) {
            // Provider is enabled
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 20000, 100, [OUTERCLASS].this.locationListener);
        } else {
            // Provider not enabled, prompt user to enable it
            Toast.makeText([OUTERCLASS].this, R.string.please_turn_on_gps, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            [OUTERCLASS].this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
});
```

My outer class has this listener set up

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        [OUTERCLASS].this.gpsLocationReceived(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

};
```

Then, whenever you want to stop listening call this.  You should at least make this call during your activity's onStop method.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
```

Comment: The second parameter on getBestProvider(locationCritera, true) checks which providers are enabled, therefore, in theory, you do not need to check if it is enabled again.

Answer (score 2):

After going through a lot of answers on Stack Overflow, I found this method to work perfectly fine and doesn't even require a lot of code.
Declare `int GPSoff = 0` as a global variable.
Now wherever you need to check for the present status of the GPS and re-direct the user to turn the GPS on, use this :

```
try {
                GPSoff = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (GPSoff == 0) {
                showMessageOKCancel("You need to turn Location On",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent onGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(onGPS);
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Comment: What is getContentResolver(), showMessageOKCancel & startActivity? They're all unresolved

Answer (score 0):

To prompt the user to enable location services you should use the new LocationRequest included in google play services, you can found the complete guide in [LocationRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html)