# How to prompt user to enable GPS_PROVIDER and/or NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Tags: android

I need to get location of user. I put in manifest

**`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`**

How to prompt user to enable GPS_PROVIDER and/or NETWORK_PROVIDER ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can start an options intent for the location settings.

```
Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
```

Comment: but this will cause the loop in the settings screen where whenever you go back it will still take to the settings screen

Comment: Why does it cause a loop?

Comment: I think it depends on where you put this code. If you start the Activity whenever your App resumes, you may end up in a loop. But it is not caused by the code itself.

Comment: you should not put this in on resume!

Answer (score 13):

LOCATION_MODE will be LOCATION_MODE_OFF if GPS is off, which will return value 0.

```
int off = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
    if(off==0){
        Intent onGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(onGPS);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Now LOCATION_MODE is deprecated, is there another solution?

Answer (score 6):

Implement LocationListner : so

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

 }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
{
    showGPSDiabledDialog();
}
}
```

Show dialog to open Settings:

```
public void showGPSDiabledDialog() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("GPS Disabled");
builder.setMessage("Gps is disabled, in order to use the application properly you need to enable GPS of your device");
builder.setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), GPS_ENABLE_REQUEST);
    }
}).setNegativeButton("No, Just Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
mGPSDialog = builder.create();
mGPSDialog.show();
}
```

In your OnCreate Method call :

```
 LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    return;
}
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

And ovveride onActivityResult method to test if the user activated correctly gps

```
    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
if (requestCode == GPS_ENABLE_REQUEST)
{
    if (mLocationManager == null)
    {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
        showGPSDiabledDialog();
    }
}
else
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
       startActivity(intent);
```

after checking gps.

complete source can be found [HERE](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/check-and-prompt-user-to-enable-gps.html) or you can refer to [SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470693/android-get-location-or-prompt-to-enable-location-service-if-disabled/3470757#3470757)

Comment: change ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS into ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS

Comment: Useful link to another SO Answer!