# Opening map showing current location and desired location on button click

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I have an image view. On clicking this image view, it must open Google map and I am using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_source+","+longitude_source+"&daddr="+latitude_dest+","+longitude_dest));

    startActivity(intent);
```

In the above code, we need to give the following:

Source Latitude, Source Longitude, Destination Latitude and Destination Longitude

Now my requirement is as below:

I am aware of Destination Latitude and Longitude. I have to get the Source Latitude and Longitude from users current location. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use LocationServices and get user current location

Comment: How can I get the Latitude and Longitude value? Can you help me with coding on that

Comment: Also, if location is not enabled, I must ask him to enable it and if not it must display a message saying operation failed

Comment: Use FusedAPI rather than LocationServices to get fast and accurate location. Check out this tutorial it is super easy - http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Comment: For prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713478/how-to-prompt-user-to-enable-gps-provider-and-or-network-provider

Comment: I am working with fragments and I am getting error with new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) .addConnectionCallbacks(this) How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Handle run time permission
//implement LocationListener in your Activity or fragment
//Add required permission in manifest

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mLocation;



 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
 mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(60 * 10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(10 * 1000);


 private void LocationRequest() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // to handle permission 6.0 and above
                mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                if (mLocation == null) {
                    BuildUtils.Log("Location", "null");
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                } 
            }
        }
    }


 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  //LocationListener implementation
        mLocation = location;
}
```

For more detail: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I have to accomplish this in fragment and I am getting error with  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this) How to solve?

Comment: Implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener