# Prompt user to enable GPS is asked once only

Tags: android, android-studio

I am prompting user to enable GPS. I coded accordingly and build is also successful. When I launched app, app prompted me to enable GPS. But When I closed that app and then opened again the app didn't prompt me to enable GPS. I created two separate java files, codes are below. App is prompting only once no matter if you close or uninstall and then reinstall, it's always prompting once only.

Can you guys tell me what is wrong I did?

Register.java

```
package com.abc.test2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register implements LocationListener {

    Context context;
    public Register(Context c)
    {
        context=c;
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(isGPSEnabled){
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,6000,10,this);
            Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return l;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.abc.test2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnGetLoc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnGetLoc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGetLoc);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);
        btnGetLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Register register = new Register(getApplicationContext());
                Location l = register.getLocation();
                if(l != null){
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lon = l.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LAT :"+lat+"/n"+"LON :"+lon,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you prompt the user to enable GPS

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior.

Once the user grant permission to the app, it will be allowed forever until the user explicitly disables it from app settings, clears app data or uninstalls the app.

Comment: No I am not asking permission during app installation, I am asking during launch of app, if gave permission it's okay but when I close app and disabled the gps. And then again launch app it's not asking me to enable location service. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing **ask for permission** with **prompt to enable location services**

As @Nabin said, the expected behavior when asking for permission is to ask it only once if it was granted the first time. If it was not granted then it will be asked again the next time.

In the other hand, is the location service enabled. If the user grants you the permission to access to location, the app could only access it if location services are enabled.

If you want to prompt your user to enable the location service if they are disabled, please, refer to this question: [How to prompt user to enable GPS_PROVIDER and/or NETWORK_PROVIDER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713478/how-to-prompt-user-to-enable-gps-provider-and-or-network-provider)

Comment: My bad, I mistakenly mixed