# How can I force Network Location?

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to turn on the Network Location ("Wireless networks" - Location determined by Wi-fi and/or mobile networks). Is this possible?

In my application, I can force 3g connection (only in Android 2.3+, I have problems with WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS on Android 2.2) and GPS Location.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via root methods if you must, however, I would recommend prompting the user in most cases.

See [Android get location or prompt to enable location service if disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470693/android-get-location-or-prompt-to-enable-location-service-if-disabled) for prompting. I'm really not sure about the root method but it is documented somewhere on the XDA-Forums I'm sure.

Comment: Root the mobile is out of my options. I need to turn on the Network provider without root..

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply not possible from Android 1.5 as a security feature, even if the user gives permission.