# why location app crashing

Tags: android, null, crash

I am trying to show my current location using GoogleMap. It runs well as long as the 'location' is turned on the phone(galaxy s4). But it crashes, when I turn off the 'location' on the phone.

Logcat is telling the provider is null at the following line

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
```

I want to pop up a message saying turn on location", instead of crashing the app. what would be a simple & nice way to do that?

code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Marker marker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(32, 270)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        LocationManager locationManager= (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

           Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14));


        }
}
```

Comment: What is the stack trace, exactly?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470693/android-get-location-or-prompt-to-enable-location-service-if-disabled

Comment: I dont know . one month ago I did not even know the basic of java.  Can you tell me , which topic to go through to achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 0):

This call `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));`
 returns `null` if Location service is disable. Your app crashed because you didn't check if `location` variable is `null` or not.