# How to prompt user to turn on location?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app where when we click a button the app launches the google map with a search query. But I need the location to be turned on to provide accurate results. Is it possible?

Comment: This is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33408809/1281180

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470693/android-get-location-or-prompt-to-enable-location-service-if-disabled

Answer (score 7):

I understood your query
here is a code which should be added on your onCreate method

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) in your AndroidManifest.xml.

General information about Android permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html).

Be aware for Android 6 permission mechanism changed ([it became iOS like](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)).

Answer (score 0):

A more complete solution that checks all location providers:

```
private fun launchLocationServicePage(context: Context) {
    val locationManager = context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val providers = locationManager.getProviders(true)
    if (providers.isEmpty()) {
        startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
    }
}
```